# Unable to produce unique folder names from a list of names through a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function in such a way that when I supply a list of folder names to it, it will add `_1` to the end of the string to produce a unique folder name if the folder name is not already in the folder_dict.

```
folder_dict = {}

def get_unique_folder_name(name):
    if name not in folder_dict:
        folder_dict[name] = name
    else:
        folder_dict[name] += '_1'

    return folder_dict[name]


items = [
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5_1',
    'Home_J5_1_1',
]

for item in items:
    print(get_unique_folder_name(item))
```

Current output:

```
Home_J5
Home_J5_1
Home_J5_1_1
Home_J5_1
Home_J5_1_1
```

Excepted output:

```
Home_J5
Home_J5_1
Home_J5_1_1
Home_J5_1_1_1
Home_J5_1_1_1_1
```

Comment: you must use `global folder_dict` at the beginning of the function, since you're editing an out-of-function variable

Comment: plus, you don't add the new created name to your folder_dict when it's created, so it won't find it on the next occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd restructure the code a little bit:

```py
def get_unique_folder_name(items):
    seen = set()
    for item in items:
        while item in seen:
            item += '_1'
        seen.add(item)
        yield item


items = [
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5_1',
    'Home_J5_1_1',
]

for item in get_unique_folder_name(items):
    print(item)
```

Prints:

```
Home_J5
Home_J5_1
Home_J5_1_1
Home_J5_1_1_1
Home_J5_1_1_1_1
```

---

EDIT: Modified structure (to avoid the global variable):

```py
def get_unique_folder_name():

    seen = set()

    def _inner(item):
        while item in seen:
            item += '_1'
        seen.add(item)
        return item

    return _inner

items = [
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5_1',
    'Home_J5_1_1',
]

u = get_unique_folder_name()

for item in items:
    print(u(item))
```

Comment: Yes, your modified approach did the trick. However, I want to loop the list of names from outside of the function, not within it.

Comment: @robots.txt I've updated the answer. If it's possible, avoid global variables.

Comment: I know my above-pasted function is not producing expected results, but it is not throwing an error due to my not using a global variable.

Comment: Moreover, this is the response I got from chatgpt: "No, it is not necessary to always use a global variable when you want to edit a variable that is outside the function. In fact, using global variables is generally discouraged in many programming scenarios because it can lead to unintended side effects and make the code less maintainable and harder to reason about."

Answer (score 1):

You do not save newly created names to your `folder_dict` variable when they are created, therefore you won't find them in the future.
I also don't think using a dictionary for that task is the best option, here's what I would use in that case:

```py
items = [
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5',
    'Home_J5_1',
    'Home_J5_1_1',
]

names = set()

for item in items:
    while item in names:
        item += "_1"
    names.add(item)
    print(item)
```